# Mark first consecutive occurances of a value in a column depending on a seperate column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, multiple-columns

Can`t figure this one out... I have a dataset in R like this one:

```
x <- c("A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "A", "C", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "C", "B","A")
z <- c(1, 1, 1, 1,2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,3, 3, 3, 3, 3,3)
y <- c(43, 32, 12, 32, 22, 42, 45, 13, 15, 61, 71, 13, 32, 24, 11, 15,33)
df <- data.frame(x,z,y)
```

So smth like this:

```
x z y
A 1 43
B 1 32
C 1 12
A 1 32
A 2 22
A 2 42
C 2 45
B 2 13
A 2 15
A 2 61
B 2 71
B 3 13
A 3 32
A 3 24
C 3 11
B 3 15
A 3 33
```

Now I would like to tag the first occurances of A if they are consecutive within each value of z.
Ideally, the end result should look like this:

```
x z y tag
A 1 43 1
B 1 32 0
C 1 12 0
A 1 32 0
A 2 22 1
A 2 42 1
C 2 45 0
B 2 13 0
A 2 15 0
A 2 61 0
B 2 71 0
B 3 13 0
A 3 32 1
A 3 24 1
C 3 11 0
B 3 15 0
A 3 33 0
```

Also I am happy for suggestions of how to rephrase the title of this question to make it more straightforward.
Thanks!

Comment: Please show us what you've tried to far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base solution

```
x <- c("A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "A", "C", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "C", "B","A")
z <- c(1, 1, 1, 1,2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,3, 3, 3, 3, 3,3)
y <- c(43, 32, 12, 32, 22, 42, 45, 13, 15, 61, 71, 13, 32, 24, 11, 15,33)
df <- data.frame(x,z,y)

within(df, {
  tag <- +(ave(as.character(df$x), df$z, FUN = function(xx) {
    r <- rle(xx %in% 'A')
    r$values[cumsum(r$values) > 1] <- FALSE
    inverse.rle(r)
  }) %in% 'TRUE')
})

#    x z  y tag
# 1  A 1 43   1
# 2  B 1 32   0
# 3  C 1 12   0
# 4  A 1 32   0
# 5  A 2 22   1
# 6  A 2 42   1
# 7  C 2 45   0
# 8  B 2 13   0
# 9  A 2 15   0
# 10 A 2 61   0
# 11 B 2 71   0
# 12 B 3 13   0
# 13 A 3 32   1
# 14 A 3 24   1
# 15 C 3 11   0
# 16 B 3 15   0
# 17 A 3 33   0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x <- c("A", "B", "C", "A", "A", "A", "C", "B", "A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "C", "B","A")
z <- c(1, 1, 1, 1,2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,3, 3, 3, 3, 3,3)
y <- c(43, 32, 12, 32, 22, 42, 45, 13, 15, 61, 71, 13, 32, 24, 11, 15,33)
df <- data.frame(x,z,y)

library(dplyr)
library(data.table)

df %>%
  group_by(z) %>%                    # for each z
  mutate(id = rleid(x),              # create group based on consecutive values
         tag = cumsum(x == "A")) %>% # create group based on consecutive As
  group_by(z, id) %>%                # for each z and id
  mutate(tag = ifelse(x == "A" & min(tag) == 1, min(tag), 0)) %>%  # tag cases where we have the 1st A or As
  ungroup() %>%                      # forget the grouping
  select(-id)                        # remove id column

# # A tibble: 17 x 4
#   x         z     y   tag
#   <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 A         1    43     1
# 2 B         1    32     0
# 3 C         1    12     0
# 4 A         1    32     0
# 5 A         2    22     1
# 6 A         2    42     1
# 7 C         2    45     0
# 8 B         2    13     0
# 9 A         2    15     0
#10 A         2    61     0
#11 B         2    71     0
#12 B         3    13     0
#13 A         3    32     1
#14 A         3    24     1
#15 C         3    11     0
#16 B         3    15     0
#17 A         3    33     0
```